# Writing BitSet to output file without overhead?

Tags: java, huffman-code, bitset

I get a line of overhead (`"java.util.BitSet"`) when writing a BitSet to an output file using `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`.

Anyway around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not an "overhead", that't the marker that lets Java figure out what type it needs to create when deserializing the object from that file.

Since `ObjectInputStream` has no idea what you have serialized into a file, and has no way for you to provide a "hint", `ObjectOutputStream` must "embed" something for the input stream to be able to decide what class needs to be instantiated. That is why it places the `"java.util.BitSet"` string in front of the data of your `BitSet`.

You cannot get around writing this marker when you use serialization capabilities built into `BitSet` class. If you are serializing the object into a file by itself, with no other objects going in with it, you could write the result of `toByteArray()` call into a file, and call `BitSet.valueOf(byteArray)` after reading `byteArray` from the file.